# Sqldelight and Postgres Column Adapter for Timestamp

Tags: sqldelight

Using this

```
  createdAt TIMESTAMP AS LocalDateTime NOT NULL,
```

compiles but the Adapter never converts from localdatetime to TIMESTAMP in postgres. Instead I receive

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "createdat" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I think this is a bug but I am asking here first to see if anybody has any ideas before submitting a bug report on github. Thanks.

```
   val localDatetimeColumnAdapter = object : ColumnAdapter<LocalDateTime,String> {
                override fun decode(databaseValue: String) =
            LocalDateTime.parse(databaseValue)
        override fun encode(value: LocalDateTime) = value.toString()


kotlin_version = 1.3.41
sqldelight_version = 1.5.0
hikari_cp_version = 4.0.3
postgresql_version = 42.2.20
```

Comment: I just tried with mysql and it works perfectly only with OffsetDateTime maybe I can save some people some time, my test shows that the postgres implementation in Sqldelight does not work with date times, only strings.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be identical to the issue submitted [here](https://github.com/AlecStrong/sql-psi/issues/153).